# Blog title cut at most inconvenient place

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, sidebar

A recent blog appears in featured blogs as

> Copying code from Stack Overflow? You might be spreading security…

BUAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA
It’s the total opposite. Let's see what that is about, kinda feel in the mood.

> Copying code from Stack Overflow? You might be spreading security vulnerabilities

Oh, the missing part of the title is really important.

That is good advice. Liked the part about "Copying without understanding". Good work Ryan.

Not sure if this is worth doing something about. But cutting titles of blogs or questions can really alter their meaning. And not everyone clicks them.

Comment: I think the term is "clickbait" which appears to be working :)

Comment: How does that change the meaning? That would be the first thing I would guess is the end of the title. Is there something else obvious I should be guessing instead that I'm missing?

Comment: @Chipster I guessed <empty_string> at end of the title. Which would cause the title to mean that copying code from SO will improve security, will "spread security..."

Comment: Hmm. I personally see the `...` and assume there is not an empty string there. But that could be just me. Anyway, now I understand your logic.

Comment: @Chipster "[...] security *best practices*"

Comment: How about a new blog post "Copying code from Stack Overflow could put your company in legal trouble and require you to open source your product" given that code in S.O. is CC-BY-SA.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed. Start spreading some security, plz.

Comment: Could you keep tabs on the click rate/retention rate before and after?  My opinion is that the clickbait would work but I'm willing to accept reality.

Comment: After some reflection... I was the one in need of a fix actually :) . But thanks for caring.

Answer (score 3):

That's the point, though.

It got your attention and it got your click.

Not everyone will click it, which is fine...but there are enough people out there that would.

Comment: Do you mean it is intentionally cut there? I assumed it was automatic due to some kind of maximum length. In the later case the point would actually be to ensure the text fits in some kind of layout. I don't really know which is the case.

Comment: I don't know if it's intentional, but whether it is or isn't, it *still* got your attention.  Which, again, is the point.